# Randomize Account Numbers, but make an account number that appears twice that same random number

Tags: excel

I'm trying to find out how I would go about randomizing account numbers in a file, and where I have the same account number making sure that number has the same random number.

I'm exporting a file to some consultants and obviously don't want them to have secure information, but I want them to be able to count the number of times an account number has appeared for reporting purposes.

Comment: Not a bad idea.  thank you.  I was hoping for a formula of some sort that would send me down a different path than this suggestion.  I can look into this though.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of an answer, as mentioned in a comment:

> Create a table that maps actual uniques to dummy random, then lookup the substitution in that table.